# Scala inner types as abstract method arguments

Tags: scala

In some code requiring subclassing of inner traits/classes I'm having trouble successfully implementing an abstract method, apparently because my type signature doesn't match.  For example:

```
trait Outer {
  trait Inner
  def score(i:Inner): Double
}
class Outer2 extends Outer {
  class Inner extends super.Inner
  def score(i:Inner) = 0.0
}
```

You might imagine that `Outer2.score` doesn't successfully implement `Outer.score` because the type `Outer2.this.Inner` doesn't match `Outer.this.Inner`.  But the compilation error message from scala-2.9.0.1 doesn't indicate this.  It says:

```
error: class Outer2 needs to be abstract, since method score in trait Outer 
of type (i: Outer2.this.Inner)Double is not defined
(Note that Outer.this.Inner does not match Outer2.this.Inner)
```

It says it is expecting an argument of type `Outer2.this.Inner`!  This is actually exactly the behavior I want.  But why doesn't my second `score` definition successfully match the type of the abstract method?

I tried to make things more clear for the compiler with the following alternative code, but I get similarly confusing error messages for it also.

```
trait Outer[This<:Outer[This]] {
  this: This =>
  trait Inner
  def score(i:This#Inner): Double
}
class Outer2 extends Outer[Outer2] {
  class Inner extends super.Inner
  def score(i:Outer2#Inner) = 0.0
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't refine the types of method parameters in an overriding method.

This works:

```
class Outer2 extends Outer {
  def score(i: super[Outer].Inner) = 0.0 

  // Or just:
  // def score(i: super.Inner) = 0
}
```

Consider if the compiler allowed your code:

```
trait Outer {
  trait Inner
  def score(i:Inner): Double
}
class Outer2 extends Outer {
  class Inner extends super.Inner { def foo = "!" }
  def score(i:Inner) = { i.foo; 0.0 }

  // !!! unsafe, no `foo` method
  score(new super[Outer].Inner{})
}
```

An overriding method may have a more specific return type, as this doesn't lead to unsound code. (At the JVM level, where the return types is included in the method signature, Bridge Methods are created to allow callers to program against the signature in the superclass and dispatch to the implementation in the subclass.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer---this makes sense.  However, I'm still wondering why my second code block doesn't work.

Comment: As an aside, I find the compiler's error message very confusing.  It says score(Outer2.this.Inner) is missing, not score(super[Outer].Inner).

Comment: Perhaps this will improve the error diagnostics: https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/e7e4acea092d70475808699b1217491500380937

Answer (score 2):

This might be a suitable workaround, depending on precise requirements:

```
trait Outer {
  trait InnerI
  type Inner <: InnerI
  def score(i:Inner): Double
}

class Outer2 extends Outer {
  class InnerI extends super.InnerI
  type Inner = InnerI
  def score(i:Inner) = 0.0
}
```